Different results of Range of a projectile
My question is from the Range of a projectile. Range is displacement of the projectile through X-axis. We all know the formula for the range $R$ of the projectile is $$R=\frac{v_0^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}$$ Where $v_0$ is the initial speed and $\theta$ is the angle at which the object is thrown. When we throw the object at 0° angle the value of range will be Zero(0) that means this value concludes that object will not displace. But actually it will displace horizontally so there should be a value of Range as per the definition. Thats my question why the concept and result differs?

The range equation tells you how far a launched object travels before it hits the ground.

Yes you both are right

The range equation you are using gives you the horizontal distance traveled by the projectile while it’s above its initial launch elevation. Only if launched from the ground will its velocity be zero at that range since it will impact the ground.
If the launch angle is zero the projectile will not rise above its initial elevation. Therefore the horizontal distance it travels while above its initial elevation is zero. That, of course, doesn't mean the horizontal distance traveled is zero.
Bottom line: The "range" is the actual horizontal distance traveled if the projectile is launched from the ground at an angle $\theta\gt 0$.
Hope this helps.

Your range equation assumes that the projectile stops at the same height it is launched at. If the launch angle is $0^\circ$, then it does not have an initial upward velocity component, and hence it never goes up and comes back down. So it stops right when it is launched.

Why it will stop ? I applied force on it so it should be go horizontally that means roll on the ground. Please ans?????

@RijuMandal I'm not saying if you roll an object in the ground it won't move. It's about what the range equation is assuming. The range equation is looking at $\Delta x$ between the two instances when $y=y_0$ for purely projectile motion that starts with an upward velocity component, not for rolling along the ground. When $\theta=0$ you don't get that. It might help to think about the limit at $\theta\to0$.

This is a really weird question...
You're talking about two entirely separate things. Usually when we refer to range, we mean the linear distance covered between point of takeoff and point of landing. If you're "throwing" it along the ground, it's just plane linear motion, and then you could calculate the distance covered (which would be infinite, if friction was neglected...), but that's not range.
This is similar to asking "wouldn't a projectile roll along the ground even after landing giving it a greater range?" Yeah, it would, BUT, that's not range anymore then.

Why that's not a range ? If the angle (Theta) can take any value so why it will be a different concept if I project it at 0° ?
